# Listview Class based view is not working properly

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

I am using class based views in my app but I am stuck at one point. I am using `ListView` and created two classes which are sub-classes of `ListView`.

**views.py**

```
class blog_home(ListView):
    paginate_by = 3
    model= Blog
    context_object_name = 'blog_title'
    template_name = 'blog.html'

class blog_search(ListView):
    paginate_by = 4

    context_object_name = 'blog_search'
    template = 'blog_search.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        self.search_result = Blog.objects.filter(title__contains = 'Static')
        return self.search_result
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$', index, name='index'),
url(r'^grappelli/', include('grappelli.urls')),
url(r'^blog/', blog_home.as_view(), name='blog_home'),
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
url(r'^blog/search/',blog_search.as_view(),name='blog_search'),
]
```

In my above code in `blog_Search()`, `get_queryset()` method is not getting called. I mean it's not working. If I use same same method in `blog_home` it does work.

blog_search not filtering. I added print statement also but not get called.

Can I create two classes with `ListView` in same file? Is this the problem?

Comment: Please show the urls.py file.

Comment: Are you getting any errors running it?

Comment: don't you need to define `model = Blog` in the second one?

Comment: @dietbacon `model` is not required if `queryset` or `get_queryset` is defined.

Comment: @DanielRoseman added urls.py

Comment: your `blog_search` url is never reached because `blog_home` is matched first for all urls starting with `blog/` ...you need to fix your urls.py

Comment: Or add '$' at the end

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to terminate your `blog/` URL entry. Without termination, it matches all URLs beginning with "blog/", including "blog/search", so no requests ever make it to the blog_search view.

```
url(r'^blog/$', blog_home.as_view(), name='blog_home'),
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
url(r'^blog/search/$',blog_search.as_view(),name='blog_search'),
```